# Storing formatted text from tinymce in database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, tinymce

I have a tinymce textarea where I put in some default text as the page is loaded. This text is formatted as bold faced and underlined. All of this works well. However, when I go to store this text in a MySQL database, I get the following error:

> Error adding email to database: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near ... at line 5

Here is how I am creating this default text inside of the textarea;

```
window.onload = function formatText() {
    tinyMCE.get("results").setContent("<b><u>RESULTS</b></u><br><br><br>");
    tinyMCE.get("upcoming_races").setContent("<b><u>UPCOMING EVENTS</b></u><br><br><br>");
    tinyMCE.get("thisweek").setContent("<b><u>THIS WEEK'S TRAINING</b></u><br><br><br>");

}
```

When I take this code out and just type the text in manually (along with formatting the text using the tinymce buttons), everything saves in the database perfectly. I don't know how to get this text to both appear with formatting AND be able to save it via a PHP/MySQL call.

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

EDIT: Here is the relevant PHP code. Note that (as previously mentioned) this code works just fine if I manually type and format the text. However, it fails when I use javascript to set up the text for me.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Emails
            (date, subject, greeting, results, upcoming, thisweek, signoff)
            VALUES 
            ('$today', '$subject', '$greeting', '$results', '$upcoming', 
            '$thisweek', '$signoff')";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

EDIT 2: Here is the echo of the $sql text. What look strange to me is all of the carriage returns, which must come from the javascript:

> INSERT INTO Emails (date, subject, greeting, results, upcoming,
>   thisweek, signoff) VALUES ('2013-07-23', 'test', ' test ', ' RESULTS
>
> ', ' UPCOMING EVENTS
>
> ', ' THIS WEEK'S TRAINING
>
> ', ' test signoff ')

Comment: your error is not in your JS code please post the relevant php code so we can take a look.

Comment: okay, this is going to be tough to debug but lets start by adding echo $sql; right before your $result = with a string that is giving you this error.  update your post with that or put it in a comment my guess is that your not escaping everything properly.

Comment: I think you are right. Maybe it relates to the <br> tags in the javascript entry???

Comment: I would take the sql and run it though phpMyAdmin or an app connected to your DB to test it out my guess is "THIS WEEK'S TRAINING" its the ' in WEEK'S which is causing the error.  You should look into PDO http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php or escaping your input.

Comment: You're exactly right. I didn't think of that (and didn't post it originally). When I take out that apostrophe from the original javascript code, it all works perfectly.

Comment: That apostrophe doesn't really matter to me. If you have an idea of how to escape that, I'd love to hear it. Otherwise, please post that as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the below function so you would need to convert your mysql to mysqli ... which you need to do anyhow or you code will not work with upcoming releases. LINK to help http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Also note this code it modified as I have it in classes so it might be a little off ... I don't use global etc etc.

```
function escapeString($string) {

    global $connection;

    // depreciated function
    if (version_compare(phpversion(),"4.3.0", "<")){
        return mysqli_escape_string($connection, $string);
    } else {
        return mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $string);
    }

}


$sql = "INSERT INTO Emails
            (date, subject, greeting, results, upcoming, thisweek, signoff)
            VALUES 
            ('" . escapeString($today) . "', '" . escapeString($subject. "', '" . escapeString($greeting) . "', '" . escapeString($results) . "', '" . escapeString($upcoming) . "', 
            '" . escapeString($thisweek) . "', '" . escapeString($signoff) . "')";
```